# I can't install a sdk, because there is a error with script

Tags: python, sdk, flir

I was installing a FLIR SDK, (Scientifc File). This is the manual for install:

[https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3504/~/getting-started-with-flir-science-file-sdk-for-python](https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3504/%7E/getting-started-with-flir-science-file-sdk-for-python)

So, in step 3, I have this error: fnv/_fnv.cpp(9290): error C2027: uso de tipo indefinido '_frame'

fnv is a extension. I found this script and, found this line where is the error. This is the script:

```
py_frame = PyFrame_New(
        tstate,            /*PyThreadState *tstate,*/
        py_code,           /*PyCodeObject *code,*/
        __pyx_d,    /*PyObject *globals,*/
        0                  /*PyObject *locals*/
    );
    if (!py_frame) goto bad;
    __Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber(py_frame, py_line); %line(9290)
```

So, I don't understend why this is happen. Can somebody help me?

I've tried change this code, but is not possible. I researched and, think that is a problem with python 3.11. I just want install this SDK for my internship, and, don't have a lot off knolodge about this.